# Single item selection from list view

Tags: android, listview

I am displaying a listview with a text view and image view. Image view is hidden. What i want is that when user selects an item from listview he sees the image in that listview item. But when he selects another item, then he should see, that image in that particular list view item. I am dng this,:::

```
    final String[] TYPE = new String[] { "Movie Top 100", "TV Top 100", "All" };

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.typescreenlistview);
    listview.setAdapter((new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.typelist, R.id.heading, TYPE)));
    listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
      {
        ImageView click = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.click);
        click.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
      }
    });
```

What condition i should use??
Thanx in advance.

Comment: you want to display a image by clicking listview? can you be little more clear?

Comment: I have 3 items in my list, i want when user clicks first item then, image is shown in that item, that will show user that item is selected,and when the user clicks on second item then that item should have image, but first item now should not have image in it....

Comment: can iterate the through the listview item and set the hide and show the things that you want

Comment: if i understood you correctly, U want to indicate the user by showing a image on list view that list item is clicked. right?

Comment: i suggest you to try Rajath's answer... it is perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ListView`, whenever a user clicks on an item, make the `ImageView` in that item visible, like so:

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
      {
        ImageView click = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.click);
        click.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    });
```

Also, I would suggest using a customized adapter, so that in `getView` you can set those listview items that are not clicked to `INVISIBLE`. See [Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) for a tutorial on using custom adapter for `ListView`

Comment: i used efficient adapter, in its get view method i called invisible bt nthng is happening.....

Comment: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;
  
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.typelist, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.text = (TextView) convertView
   .findViewById(R.id.heading);
   convertView.setTag(holder);
   
   
   holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.click);
   convertView.setTag(holder);
   holder.image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);